# Woocommerce Change Position of Product Variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, product-variations

I am trying to change the position of the `Product Variations` inside the `Single Product Page`. Right now, they appear under the `Short Description` but I want them to appear before the `Product's Short Description`, right after the product `Title` and `Price`.

The code I have for the moment is the following:

```
function move_linked_variation_options()
{

    remove_action('woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30);
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 10);
}

add_action('init', 'move_linked_variation_options');
```

It works great when products have variations, but when I navigate to a product that has no variations, it just throws an error which is the following:

[image: the error]

Do you have any idea why this is happening?
Should I have some kind of conditional inside the function?
Am I missing any action before the position change?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'move_linked_variation_options' );
function move_linked_variation_options() {
    global $product;
    
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 10 );
    }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn’t work. It throws an error saying that we called an undefined function is_type()

Comment: I edited your answer because I found the solution. your code was correct, but we were hooking these actions too soon in `wp_head`. so i just changed the hook to `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` and it worked perfectly! Let's wait for the admins to accept my edit and then I will mark your answer as correct.